# Extracting a string between two characters

Tags: c#, regex, using

How do I extract a string between two characters using a regular expression?
For example:

```
{sdjhjkfd 78983njdsjnc cxjkc/m/xc;dfo}/mnvckjdf{jhdfkjhxbbnkhfd}
```

How to get string between `{` and `}`?

Answer (score 4):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)[^{}]*(?=\})");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
```

gets you all text between innermost, correctly balanced braces. No escaped braces are allowed.